# Is it possible to render word document from Rmarkdown Tufte template?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, tufte

I am writing a document in RStudio / Rmarkdown using Tufte style template. It creates pdf or html documents but is it possible to get the same output as a Word document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, or at least not easily as the inner workings as the style template are implemented *explicitly* for pdf and html.

You could look into adding this for Word yourself. I do not know how feasible that is.

I have forked the Tufte style and updated it to something a wee bit more modern looking (crisper font, no pale yellow background, ...) which I called 'tint' (for 'tint is not Tufte', gotta remain recursive).  Its [web page](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/tint.html), the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/tint), and [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/package=tint) all have some more information.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question, please.  The document I am writing is in Turkish. How can I translate the reserved words like "Figure, Table" etc.?

Comment: Aiie. I once had that a really time ago for German and French, respectively.  One way is to essentially make a copy, say, "mytufte" and to actually replace the strings in the code. Sometimes the function just bring up 'variables' to print values -- in that case you could preassign them.  That all depends, but is more of a latex question (if you go via pdf).